# How to achieve awareness of "kill" events in a scene

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d

I have been doing a RPG game in Unity with C # and when doing a system of quests, specifically those of killing a certain number of enemies, I found the problem of having 3 enemies in the scene and being the target of the quest: Kill 3 enemies. If I kill them before activating the quest and later active the quest does not give me the reward (in this case experience). How can I tell the enemies and make that if the quest detects that I have already killed the necessary enemies to get the quest give me the reward equally?

---

Here the two needed scripts i think:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class QuestObject : MonoBehaviour {

    public int questNumber;

    public QuestManager qManager;

    public string startText;
    public string endText;

    public bool isItemQuest;
    public string targetItem;

    public bool isEnemyQuest;
    public string targetEnemy;
    public int enemiesToKill;
    private int enemyKillCount;

    private PlayerStats playerStats;
    public int EXPToGive;

    void Start () {
        playerStats = FindObjectOfType <PlayerStats> ();
    }

    void Update () {

        if (isItemQuest) {

            if (qManager.itemCollected == targetItem) {

                qManager.itemCollected = null;
                EndQuest ();
            }
        }


        if (isEnemyQuest) {

            if (qManager.enemyKilled == targetEnemy) {

                qManager.enemyKilled = null;

                enemyKillCount++;

            }

            if (enemyKillCount >= enemiesToKill) {

                EndQuest ();

            }
        }
    }

    public void StartQuest (){
        qManager.ShowQuestText (startText);



    }

    public void EndQuest (){
        qManager.ShowQuestText (endText);
        playerStats.AddEXP (EXPToGive);
        qManager.questCompleted [questNumber] = true;
        gameObject.SetActive (false);


    }
}
```

---

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class EnemyHealth : MonoBehaviour {

    public int startingHealth;                                  
    public int currentHealth;                                   
    public GameObject damageBurst;
    private PlayerStats playerStats;
    public int EXPToGive;

    public string enemyQuestName;
    private QuestManager qManager;




    void Start ()
    {
        // Setting up the references.
        //anim = GetComponent <Animator> ();
        //enemyAudio = GetComponent <AudioSource> ();
        //enemyMovement = GetComponent <EnemyMovement> ();
        //enemyAttacking = GetComponentInChildren <EnemyAttack> ();
        // Set the initial health of the player.
        currentHealth = startingHealth;
        playerStats = FindObjectOfType <PlayerStats> ();
        qManager = FindObjectOfType <QuestManager> ();
    }



    void Update ()
    {
        if (currentHealth <= 0) {

            qManager.enemyKilled = enemyQuestName;

            Destroy (gameObject);
            playerStats.AddEXP (EXPToGive);
        }
    } 


    public void TakeDamage (int amountDamage)
    {
        // Reduce the current health by the damage amount.
        currentHealth -= amountDamage;
        Instantiate (damageBurst, transform.position, transform.rotation);


    }

    public void SetMaxHelth () {
        currentHealth = startingHealth;
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can several approach. The most straight-forward is to use static.

The purpose of static is for the variable/method to belong to the class instead of an instance of the class.

In your case, you want each enemy to have its own health, this cannot be static.
And you want to count how many instances there are in the scene from the class. So static is fine.

```
public class Enemy:MonoBehaviour
{
     private static int enemyCount = 0;
     public static int EnemyCount {get{ return enemyCount;} }
     public event Action<int> RaiseEnemyDeath;
     public static void ResetEnemyCount(){
          enemyCount = 0;
     }

     private int health;
     public void Damage(int damage)
     { 
         CheckForDamage(); // here you check that damage is not neg or too big...
         this.health -= damage;
         if(this.health <= 0)
         { 
             OnDeath(); 
         }
     }
     void OnActivate() 
     { 
         enemyCount++; 
         this.health = 20;
     }
     void OnDeath()
    { 
         enemyCount--; 
         RaiseEnemyDeath(enemyCount); // Should check for nullity...
    }
}
```

This one is fairly simple. The first part is all static and is relevant to the class. The second part is relevant to the instance. If you use a pool of enemy and then reuse the same instance multiple times, the OnActivate method is called when you make the enemy alive in the scene (it may have been there for a while as inactive). Then when the health is down, kill the enemy (there are not all the required actions there...) and trigger the event.

Using the public static property, you can know what is the enemy count from a GameManager (Enemy should not affect the gameplay, only takes care of the enemy).

```
public class GameManager:MonoBehaviour
{
    void Start()
    {
         Enemy.RaiseEnemyDeath += Enemy_RaiseEnemyDeath;
    }
    void Enemy_RaiseEnemyDeath(int count)
    {
        if(count < 0){ // End of level }
        // You can also access enemyCount
        int count = Enemy.EnemyCount;
    }
}
```

The good point of using this principle is that Enemy has no clue about GameManager and can be reused in another game without any modification. The GameManager is a higher level entity and knows about it.

Comment: I like the aproach of using events, but i'd even more like that solution if you did not use static. But have an upvote for providing a good solution.

Comment: Static here is actually appropriate. The number of enemy is relevant to the Enemy class. You can also achieve with some higher level manager. Static is required here when you think that even though there are no Enemy instances, you can still check the value of EnemyCount. If static is not valid here, then it has no reason to be at all in programming in general.

Answer (score 3):

One Aproach would be to create some type of "WorldManager" which counts every Enemy which has been slain. And when Starting a quest this quest could check the WorldManagers kill count and add it to it's own count.

```
   public void StartQuest (){
        qManager.ShowQuestText (startText);
        this.enemyKillCount += worldManager.GetKillCount();
    }
```

In your enemy class you have to add a kill to your worldManager.

```
 void Update ()
    {
        if (currentHealth <= 0) {

            qManager.enemyKilled = enemyQuestName;
            this.worldManager.AddKill(this)
            Destroy (gameObject);
            playerStats.AddEXP (EXPToGive);
        }
    }
```

Alternative:

Make your QManager be aware of every kill in a Scene. 
You can achieve this through many ways.
One of them is passing your EnemyObject an reference of your Qmanager and do the same as with the "WorldManager" provided above, or you use Messaging and fire a Message targeting the QManager when an enemy is slain.

Alternative 2:
Throw an Event when an enemy has been slain and subscribe to it on your QManager/WorldManager. This way u can reuse your enemy class in every game. From my point of view static dependencies are evil, but there are many discussions and SO and everywhere on the internet about that.

Comment: Ok thanks, but i don't understand where the AddKill(this) is sending this information and where have I to put the AddKill. And GetKillCount()? And I don't know how to do the Enemy Counter can you help me please? I have two separated type of enemies Goblins and Slimes.